# is there any help about the typeorm orwhere

Tags: sql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

`src/resolver/record/record.query.ts` should be able to not pass company id for user that are `authUser.isSuperuser`

this will not work as expected.
Please do not search for the company in the first place if no company was passed.
with this change it would do the following query:

`r.name ILIKE "" OR r.company = null AND (r.secure = false OR r.author = 123)`
-> showing all records that match the name search OR where the user has access

```
public async search(
    company: CompanyEntity,
    query: string,
    start: number = 0,
    limit: number = 50,
    user: UserEntity = null,
    filter: RecordPagerFilterInputModel = null
  ): Promise<[RecordEntity[], number]> {

    const qb = this.recordRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('r')
      .where('r.meetingRecord IS NULL')
      .andWhere('r.name ILIKE ""')
      .orWhere('r.company = null')
      .andWhere('(r.secure = false OR r.author = 123)')
      .setParameters({
        query: `%${query}%`,
        company: company.id,
        secure: false,
        author: user ? user.id : -1,
      })
      .orderBy('r.created', 'DESC')
    console.log('qb',qb.getQuery())

    if (filter && filter.secure !== undefined) {
      qb.andWhere('r.secure = :filterSecure', { filterSecure: filter.secure })
    }

    if (filter && filter.own !== undefined) {
      qb.andWhere(filter.own ? 'r.author = :author' : 'r.author <> :author')
    }

    if (filter && filter.language !== undefined) {
      qb.andWhere('r.language = :filterLanguage', { filterLanguage: filter.language })
    }

    if (filter && filter.status !== undefined) {
      qb.andWhere('r.status IN (:...filterStatus)', { filterStatus: filter.status })
    }

    qb.skip(start)
    qb.take(limit)

    return await qb.getManyAndCount()
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For your question, I don't clearly understand what it is and what you need. Could you update the question with what you exactly need and a little bit of context about your code?

Answer (score 0):

you should use () in all orWhere:

```
.orWhere(((r.name ILIKE "" OR r.company = null) AND (r.secure = false OR r.author = 123)))
```